# problem of colors with \AtBeginShipoutBox command

Tags: color, atbegshi, shipout

When I compile this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutInit

\AtBeginShipout{%
 \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(0,-\paperheight){{\color{red}\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I get (page 2)

[image]

**Question:** why labels are in black?

Comment: Interesting how [`color`](http://ctan.org/pkg/color) is a little more forgiving than [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). Loading the latter makes `\color{red}` not influence the `\box\AtBeginShipoutBox`.

Comment: @Werner yes, this may be will the next question I find that with `xcolor` the color change starting from page 2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain the appropriate alignment in lists (specifically for `itemize` and `enumerate`), LaTeX *boxes* the item labels. And once things are boxed, it's fixed and your `\color` command doesn't reach it.

Here's a minimal example replicating the behaviour using the temporary box `\@tempboxa`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,picture,atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{%
 \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(0,-\paperheight){{\color{red}\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% Since this is boxed, it will remain black
\sbox\@tempboxa{this is some text}\usebox\@tempboxa
\makeatother

\begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Last
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `pdflatex` you can set the color using a `\pdfliteral` which affects *everything*, because the color is rendered in the viewer and TeX doesn't know about it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutInit

\AtBeginShipout{%
 \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(0,-\paperheight){%
    % Color code:        R G B
    \pdfliteral direct{q 1 0 0 rg}%
    \box\AtBeginShipoutBox%
    \pdfliteral direct{Q}%
  }%
 }%
}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image]